# can a windows server 2012 act as a domain controller to only a select range of ip addresses?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server

I am working with a company that wishes to migrate from a peer to peer network to a domain controller.  They have already purchased a Windows 2012 server and have set it up for DNS and DHCP, Active Directory is next.
Some of their workstations are running Windows 7 Home Premium and can not log on to a domain.
Is it possible, on this single server, to assign a specific range of ip addresses for the domain controller, and have another range of ip addresses (same subnet)for the dhcp server to use without domain authentication, so the windows 7 home boxes can still get an ip address?

Answer (score 3):

The DHCP server can service both domain members and non-domain members. You don't need to do anything special to have it service non-domain members. Simply join the domain from the machines you wish to join the domain and leave the Windows 7 Home Premium machines as is. They'll happily get an ip address from your DHCP server in your AD domain.

You'll need to authorize the DHCP server in AD in order for it to service **any** clients, but once you do that it will service any DHCP clients on the same physical network segment.